# How to create multiple line abbreviations vim

Tags: perl, vim

How can I create multiple line VIM abbreviations.

For example I want to create an abbreviation like `subflowclass` which expands into:

```
package foo;

sub new {

}

sub test {

}

sub abc {

}

1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the plugins [SnipMate](https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate) and [UltiSnips](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips).

They provide the features you would like. You make a file called `filetype.snippets` (so if you want to make snippets for perl you would use `perl.snippets`). Then you can define your snippets from there:

For example, in `java.snippets` I have the following snippet:

```
snippet println
    System.out.println(${0});
```

Now, whenever I type println followed by tab (I use snipmate, not sure if ultisnips is the same keybinding) it expands to

```
System.out.println(*Cursor here*);
```

The `${0}` defines a tabstop so you can jump to arguments or whatnot.

In addition, there are a bunch of pre-defined snippets available for download [here](https://github.com/honza/vim-snippets) (just put the snippets folder in your bundle folder if using pathogen). They work for both snipmate and ultisnips.

An example snippet for you would be:

```
snippet subflowclass
    package foo;

    sub ${1:new} {

    }

    sub ${2:test} {

    }

    sub ${3:abc} {

    }

    1;
```

The `${n:name}` notation means put a tabstop there (a place the user can jump to by pressing tab) and give it the default value of `name`.

Comment: No problem, I'm glad I was able to help you!